# Highlight elements in a css grid layout using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a css grid with 25 `div` elements. Each element should switch between being highlighted and normal when clicked on.

Since each element can be individually turned on and off, I made a `box_state` variable for each and set it to `false` as initial value so it can be set to `true` once its turned on.

To highlight each element I got this block of code:

```
    document.querySelector("#n_1").onclick = function() {
    if (box_1_state === false) {
        document.querySelector("#n_1").style.filter = "brightness(150%)";
        box_1_state = true;
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#n_1").style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
        box_1_state = false;
    }

}
```

`n_1` is the name of the `div` in the html file and `box_1_state` is the variable mentioned above.

So to make this work I have to make the code block above 25 times which kind of seems it could be done easier. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you paste the HTML you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- All you need is [**Element.classList.toggle()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and a specific **CSS class**, i.e: `"is-active"`
- PS: filter brightness expects a maximal value of 100%

```js
const ELS_box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
ELS_box.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("is-active");
}))
```

```css
.boxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 30px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 30px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.box {
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
}

.box.is-active {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a class, you can store its state in a [custom attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
divs.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (e.dataset.brightened != "true") {
      e.style.filter = "brightness(150%)";
      e.dataset.brightened = "true";
    } else {
      e.style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
      e.dataset.brightened = "false";
    }
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

A method to automate this is by surrounding your code with a loop, and then use the loop's iterator/index to use as the querySelector

```
let numberOfDivElements = 25;
let box_states = [];

for (let iterator = 0; iterator < numberOfDivElements; iterator++) {
    // Initialize an array to store your "box states", whether true or false
    box_states[iterator] = false;
}

for (let iterator = 0; iterator < numberOfDivElements; iterator++) {
    let boxSelector = "#n_" + iterator;

    // Your example code
    document.querySelector(boxSelector).onclick = function() {
        if (box_states[iterator] === false) {
            document.querySelector(boxSelector).style.filter = "brightness(150%)";
            box_states[iterator] = true;
        } else {
            document.querySelector(boxSelector).style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
            box_states[iterator] = false;
        }
    }
    // End of your example code

}
```